# Derivative of tensor product with respect to tensor

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

I'm current stuck on a continuum mechanics problem, in which I need to find:
$$
\nabla \cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial \nabla P}\left[G\circ\left(\nabla P \otimes \nabla P\right)\right]
$$
Where $P$ is a vector in R3, i.e.  $P = P_i,P_j,P_k$, and $G$ is a coefficient tensor with the same size as $\nabla P \otimes \nabla P$.

Of course, I could expand it into each component of the grad(P) tensors, but with 81 terms this would become a nightmare fairly soon.

Is there an elegant way to simplify this?

Comment: Heuristically, product rule tells us that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \nabla P}\left(\nabla P\otimes\nabla P\right) = (I + \nabla P )\otimes (I+\nabla P)$$ where $I$ is a rank $4$ identity tensor. From here the problem just simplifies to taking divergence of the rank $2$ tensor which is a formula you should have.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks for the tip! However, shouldn't I be a rank 2 identity tensor, such that it can be added to grad(P), which is also rank 2?

Comment: Good point, the change I made to combine the two terms was a mistake. Keep them separated. And it would be identity in the sense that there are blocks of identity matrices, but not necessarily the kronecker delta type identity down the "diagonal" only.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Sorry I think you've lost me there (vector calculus is definitely out of my comfort zone). Could you explain a little bit more what you mean?

Comment: Is $G\left(\nabla P \otimes \nabla P\right)$ the tensor-valued function $G$ evaluated at $\nabla P \otimes \nabla P$, or a tensor product between $G$ and $\nabla P \otimes \nabla P$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $G$ is a scalar-valued coefficient tensor that is multiplied (Hadamard/element-wise product) with $\nabla P \otimes \nabla P$. Let me edit the question.

Comment: So here's where I get to:
$\nabla \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \nabla P}[G\circ(\nabla P \otimes \nabla P)] = \nabla \cdot G \circ \frac{\partial}{\partial \nabla P}(I \otimes \nabla P + \nabla P \otimes I)$. 
What happens next?